# Pan point on Google Map to specific pixel position on screen (API v3)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When `overlay` is a Google maps overlay and `offsetx, offsety` is the pixel distance from the maps center that I want to pan `latlong` to, the following works.

```js
var projection = overlay.getProjection();
var pxlocation = projection.fromLatLngToContainerPixel(latlong);
map.panTo(projection.fromContainerPixelToLatLng(new google.maps.Point(pxlocation.x+offsetx,pxlocation.y+offsety)));
```

However, I don't always have an overlay on the map and `map.getProjection()` returns a `projection`, not a `MapCanvasProjection` which does not have the methods I need.

Is there a way to do this without making an overlay specificaly for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since nobody has come up with a better way, here's my solution. Make an overlay with the sole job of giving me a `MapCanvasProjection` object.

```js
var helper = new google.maps.OverlayView();
helper.setMap(map);
helper.draw = function () { 
    if (!this.ready) { 
        this.ready = true; 
        google.maps.event.trigger(this, 'ready'); 
    } 
}; 
var projection = helper.getProjection();
...
```

Hope this helps someone. Better suggestions welcome.

Comment: The google docs says, "The projection is not initialized until onAdd is called by the API." So calling helper.getProjection(); immediately after creating helper, returns null. So use this: 
helper.onAdd = function(){
    projection = helper.getProjection();
};