# Google Maps API shows labels to markers with no overlap

Tags: api, google-maps, label, overlap, markers

My goal is to show label texts to markers, but as long as screen makes it somehow possible, with no overlap on the label textes.

I have something like this in mind:
[image]

I already saw my goal on a map, but I don't have any code from it:
[image]

What to do?

Comment: Perhaps try the approach here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092085/pixel-distance-in-google-map-api-v3-to-avoid-overlapping-labels-overlays
If it's just your markers, you can use [MarkerClusters](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers) or the [Spiderfier](https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there another easier solution? I think calculating this stuff can be very complicated and must be done for every zoom level again.

Comment: Did you found any soluntion.I also in great need for this.And where did yo saw it?

Comment: No. We changed to use GoogleMaps MarkerClusterer, which imo anyway looks better (imagine you have 1000+ marker on map): https://github.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer